# PEP and multiline `__str__` return

Tags: python, pep8

In python, is there a section of a PEP against the method `__str__` returning a multiline string?

**Pro:** PyCharm does not tell me off and Google draws a blank

**Contra:** I could see it would cause an inelegant response if someone concatenated it, feels un-pythonic and I am not sure I can recall seeing one —bar in my own code

So I am not sure if to just have a multiline `__str__` return (keep it simple) or to leave alone `__str__` (*i.e.* returns `<class foo>`) and have a special module (*e.g.* `foo.report()`).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between \_\_str\_\_ and \_\_repr\_\_ in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr-in-python)

Comment: I don't think this is a `__str__` vs `__repr__` dupe though, if anything, it's more of an opinion based question. But I guess you could also say that it already has an answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with it.  There are plenty of classes that return multiline values for `str` (such as pandas DataFrames and Series).  You can return whatever format you think best represents the object.

Comment: That Pandas uses multiline returns is all the proof in favor I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The `__str__` method is meant to return a string value that is human readable. If there is any use in having multiple lines for that (such as the string representation of a board game that has two dimensions), you should do that. If it is meant to be consumed by another source, you may want to use a custom method that includes the appropriate information in the appropriate format, or override `__repr__`, which is meant to return an unambiguous string representation.